# Infer super types in a tuple of generic wrappers

Tags: typescript, generics, tuples, super, inference

I'm trying to create a type constraint in TypeScript that enforces supertype relationship for a wrapped type.
Let's suppose I defined the following type (and a utility function to build it):

```
interface Wrapper<T> { 
    item: T; 
}

function wrap<T>(t: T): Wrapper<T> { 
    return { item: t } 
}
```

Then I've created the following type to infer the super type relationship (I'm explaining below the `0` vs `never` issue):

```
type SuperTypesWrappers<C, T extends ReadonlyArray<Wrapper<any>>> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Wrapper<infer V> ?
    C extends V ? Wrapper<V> :
    0 : 0 // never : never  -> doesn't work
};
```

I defined 3 example wrappers, like the following:

```
interface A { a: string; }
const A = wrap<A>({ a: 'a' });

interface B { b: string; }
const B = wrap<B>({ b: 'b' });

interface C extends B { c: string; }
const C = wrap<C>({ b: 'b', c: 'c' });
```

And a type to verify the constraint:

```
// WORKS FINE: type Test1 = [0, Wrapper<B>]
type Test1 = SuperTypesWrappers<C, [typeof A, typeof B]>;
```

As expected, the first item in the type array is `0` because `A` is not supertype for `C`, but `B` is.

So far, so good.

Then I created an aux type to enforce the array validity as a whole: it returns the array type *as it is*, or `never`, if it has some items that are not `Wrapper<X>`:

```
type ValidSuperTypesWrappers<X> = X extends ReadonlyArray<Wrapper<any>> ? X : never;

// WORKS FINE: never
type Test2 = ValidSuperTypesWrappers<Test1>;
```

Then I created a function that leverages both types:

```
export function defineHierarchy<C, T extends ReadonlyArray<Wrapper<any>>>(
    wrapper: Wrapper<C>, 
    superWrappers: ValidSuperTypesWrappers<SuperTypesWrappers<C, T>>
): ValidSuperTypesWrappers<SuperTypesWrappers<C, T>> {
    // some implementation
    return superWrappers;
}
```

And when I invoke it, I'm expecting the second parameter to be checked, and in the following example it should raise a type error (based on what happens in the example types `Test1` and `Test2`):

```
// DOES NOT WORK: should raise type error for the array argument!
// inferred type: const h: readonly Wrapper<any>[]
const h = defineHierarchy(C, [A, B]);
```

Probably I'm missing something, or could it be a bug? How can I change these types to make it work in the `defineHierarchy` function above (possibly without specifying the generic type arguments in the function call)?

---

**NOTE 1:** If I use `never : never` in `SuperTypesWrappers`, even `Test2` doesn't work:

```
// DOES NOT WORK: type Test2 = [never, Wrapper<B>]
type Test2 = ValidSuperTypesWrappers<Test1>;
```

**NOTE 2:** I would not like to rely on `Partial<T>` to express a supertype constraint, the type above should represent the constraint better.

Comment: Your approach seems overly complicated. TS won't try to do inference from `ValidSuperTypesWrappers<SuperTypesWrappers<C, T>>` can't tell you exactly what is tripping it up .. but the conditional types are hard to work back to inferring `T`. This seems to work and is simpler:

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOpTgB09APAFQD5kBvZYSAWwC5l8BuZAXwCgEB7EAZzGQEFkAXlLkqtMnFoByOFObN6bTj2QAhISIoQaIgEbTdcpgqXdeAYQ1ktOsvuRTDAGmQJpCIyZZgAnjmQAqiDAnPjsAJLg0FwQCGAhILgBxMIsyMgAFAHIEAAekCAAJlzIcCA+yAD8mQDWtAEAlIKEAG7swIXItCAQLdANOfkQRSUZGXXkIDDQyOFNre2FA9XhXcg9fVAsLHmY7FC8MACuIHEJyIUQMKAQABLA0HBQCAAWPriWeQXFgcGhEVEoDEzpwCABtKQ2KQAXUILnwg2+JXQWBwUFwZR8hEIGTS6WQAHcMNhoLQUST0eY4cg8ekuEc0eS0VxaAAlCBwQqcAA2Pj4UAw7yILAabI5XJAvP5goIxBItOQUAgYCOUBAyHpjOJzMUrFMKheGku1x690ezzeGXMLjBfBcqmhDXoQA

Comment: Interesting. So you basically approached the problem the other way around: defining a union based on the "component types" provided in the array and checking the first parameter satisfy it. I'm going to experiment a little bit later, but seems promising. Thanks